# Supabase database size issue

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I am quite new to Supabase.

Please clarify this:

I have a table in the database and its only 32KB in size.(2 columns and 2 rows of data only)

So why it is showing a Database Space Usage (under Settings > Database Usage)  as 30 MB out of 512 MB

Does this resets every month?

Please clarify this, I think supabase is cool. But if you increase the size without any reason, thats quite bad.

Answer (score 4):

The value that you're seeing in the "Database space" on the Billing settings page is an average value of the size of your database based on your current billing cycle, rather than the size of your database at that current point in time.

This is explained at : https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/disk-usage

To see the actual size the database is using, run this in SQL Editor :

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('postgres'));
```

Comment: Does that mean this "Database Space" resets every month? Suppose that, I have Database Space usage of 400 MB out of 512 MB in the month of January. Does this 400MB resets to 0MB after the end of January? Please let me know.

Comment: It never resets to 0, it reflects the size of the database. It might reduce as time passes but that depends whether you clear up your tables/ run vacuums regularly

Comment: It seems like the linked page has been moved to https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/database-usage

Comment: Hello, why is the usage so high though? If I go into Database > Tables, my tables only take up a few kB (around 300kB), however in my usage I see 27 MB. Do you know why this is? Thanks :)

Comment: I think PostgreSQL can take anywhere from 8 to 15 MB of hard drive space once installed. To test this, you can create a blank project and check the DB size usage.